# Python array optimization with two constraints

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize

I have an optimization problem where I'm trying to find an array that needs to optimize two functions simultaneously.

In the minimal example below I have two known arrays `w` and `x` and an *unknown* array `y`. I initialize array `y` to contains only 1s.

I then specify function `np.sqrt(np.sum((x-np.array)**2)` and want to find the array `y` where

`np.sqrt(np.sum((x-y)**2)`  approaches `5`

`np.sqrt(np.sum((w-y)**2)`  approaches `8`

The code below can be used to successfully optimize `y` with respect to a single array, but I would like to find that the solution that optimizes `y` with respect to both `x` and `y` simultaneously, but am unsure how to specify the two constraints.

`y` should only consist of values greater than 0.

Any ideas on how to go about this ?

```
w = np.array([6, 3, 1, 0, 2])
x = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

def func(x, y):

    z = np.sqrt(np.sum((x-y)**2)) - 5
    return  np.zeros(x.shape[0],) + z

r = opt.root(func, x0=y, method='hybr')
print(r.x)
# array([1.97522498 3.47287981 5.1943792  2.10120135 4.09593969])

print(np.sqrt(np.sum((x-r.x)**2)))
# 5.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `scipy.optimize.minimize` instead of `root`, Here you have multiple solver options and some of them (ie `SLSQP`) allow you to specify multiple constraints. Note that I changed the variable names so that `x` is the array you want to optimise and `y` and `z` define the constraints.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

x0 = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
y = np.array([6, 3, 1, 0, 2])
z = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

constraint_x = dict(type='ineq',
                    fun=lambda x: x)   # fulfilled if > 0
constraint_y = dict(type='eq',
                    fun=lambda x: np.linalg.norm(x-y) - 5)  # fulfilled if == 0
constraint_z = dict(type='eq',
                    fun=lambda x: np.linalg.norm(x-z) - 8)  # fulfilled if == 0

res = minimize(fun=lambda x: np.linalg.norm(x), constraints=[constraint_y, constraint_z], x0=x0,
               method='SLSQP', options=dict(ftol=1e-8))  # default 1e-6

print(res.x)                    # [1.55517124 1.44981672 1.46921122 1.61335466 2.13174483]
print(np.linalg.norm(res.x-y))  # 5.00000000137866
print(np.linalg.norm(res.x-z))  # 8.000000000930026
```

This is a minimizer so besides the constraints it also wants a function to minimize, I chose just the norm of `y`, but setting the function to a constant (ie lambda x: 1) would have also worked.
Note also that the constraints are not *exactly* fulfilled, you can increase the accuracy by setting optional argument `ftol` to a smaller value ie `1e-10`.
For more information see also the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) and the corresponding sections for each solver.